# how can i decrease the execution time?

Tags: java, runtime-error

i need this code to run under 0.15 seconds. here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=s.nextInt();
        int k=s.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=(n-i); j++)System.out.print(" ");
            for(int j=1;j<=((2*i)+1);j++) System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int i=k; i<=n;i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=(n-i); j++)System.out.print(" ");
                for(int j=1;j<=k;j++)System.out.print("*");
                for(int j=1;j<=((2*(i-k))+1);j++)System.out.print(" ");
                for(int j=1;j<=k;j++)System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i=(n-1); i>=k;i--) {
            for(int j=1; j<=(n-i); j++)System.out.print(" ");
                for(int j=1;j<=k;j++)System.out.print("*");
                for(int j=1;j<=((2*(i-k))+1);j++)System.out.print(" ");
                for(int j=1;j<=k;j++)System.out.print("*");
                System.out.println();
        }
            for(int i=(k-1);i>=0;i--) {
                for(int j=1; j<=(n-i); j++)System.out.print(" ");
                for(int j=1;j<=((2*i)+1);j++) System.out.print("*");
                System.out.println();
            }
    }

}
```

and this is the example input and output.

```
input:
n=10
k=3
output:
          *
         ***
        *****
       *** ***
      ***   ***
     ***     ***
    ***       ***
   ***         ***
  ***           ***
 ***             ***
***               ***
 ***             ***
  ***           ***
   ***         ***
    ***       ***
     ***     ***
      ***   ***
       *** ***
        *****
         ***
          *
```

what changes can i make in it to do so? i spent so much time thinking on it but it got me nowhere.
..................................................................................................

Comment: How do you estimate performance time?

Comment: minimize the number of loops, and the number of inputs. try and read both inputs as a nextLine, and split the result instead of calling nextInt() twice

Comment: minimize calls to `System.out` methods, use a `StringBuilder` to create the output instead

Comment: Instead of printing spaces out one at a time, have a string which is the largest number of spaces you may ever need, and use a substring of it the proper length.

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but perhaps use a BufferedReader rather than a Scanner.

Comment: I don't want to be a curmudgeon, but if you need performance, Java is *not* the way to go.

Comment: this code takes 5 milliseconds to run on my moderate machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try with StringBuilder and [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) to do the string padding for you, something like this:

```
public static void print2(int n, int k) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", n-i,' '));

        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", 2*i+1,'*'));
        output.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    for (int i = k; i <= n; i++) {
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", n-i,' '));
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", k,'*'));
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", 2*(i-k)+1,' '));
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", k,'*'));
        output.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    for (int i = (n - 1); i >= k; i--) {
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", n-i,' '));
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", k,'*'));
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", 2*(i-k)+1,' '));
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", k,'*'));
        output.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    for (int i = (k - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", n-i,' '));
        output.append(StringUtils.leftPad("", 2*i+1,'*'));
        output.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
```

see this is the very same logic you had. To improve further, you would need to rework the algorithm. On my virtual host it runs about 5x faster.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine your code is fast enough, but there are still some improvements you can make:

First improvement would be not to print out each character on its own, but using a `java.lang.StringBuilder` instead:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type n:");
        int n = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("type k:");
        int k = s.nextInt();
        long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (n - i); j++)
                stringBuilder.append(' ');
            for (int j = 1; j <= ((2 * i) + 1); j++)
                stringBuilder.append('*');
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
        for (int i = k; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (n - i); j++)
                stringBuilder.append(' ');
            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
                stringBuilder.append('*');
            for (int j = 1; j <= ((2 * (i - k)) + 1); j++)
                stringBuilder.append(' ');
            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
                stringBuilder.append('*');
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }

        for (int i = (n - 1); i >= k; i--) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (n - i); j++)
                stringBuilder.append(' ');
            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
                stringBuilder.append('*');
            for (int j = 1; j <= ((2 * (i - k)) + 1); j++)
                stringBuilder.append(' ');
            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
                stringBuilder.append('*');
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
        for (int i = (k - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (n - i); j++)
                stringBuilder.append(' ');
            for (int j = 1; j <= ((2 * i) + 1); j++)
                stringBuilder.append('*');
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("UsedTime : " + ((endtime - starttime) * 0.001) + "s");
}
```

If this is not enough, you will have to change your paint algorithm, if this is the case, please make a comment. I will then have a look on the algorithm too.

Ok i know have tested severall things:

This ended in following "benchmark" times (average over 10'000 runs):

> original: 0.001223081s  (319.17562630480165 times slower than fastest)
>
> builder:  6.977200000000001E-5s  (18.207724425887264 times slower than
>   fastest)
>
> myCode:   3.832E-6s  (fastest)
>
> TomSCode: 7.3558E-5s  (19.19572025052192 times slower than fastest)

TomS Code is the proposed solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60502890/12558456

As you can see, following code was slightly faster then the one above, but I have no idea why this is so...

```
    private static long paintMyCode(int n, int k) {
        long starttime = System.nanoTime();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int y = 0; y <= n * 2; y++) {
            int Δy = Math.abs(n - y);
            for (int x = 0; x <= n * 2; x++) {
                int d = Δy + Math.abs(n - x);
                if (d <= n && n - k < d) {
                    stringBuilder.append('*');
                } else {
                    stringBuilder.append(' ');
                }
            }
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
        long endtime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(stringBuilder);
        return endtime - starttime;
    }
```

Comment: a hint given is that the diameter of the diamond is 2n+1

Comment: Which time exactly do you need? The time for calculation or all the time from start of calculation to all output is printed out. (I'm asking, because on my machine i get following times: [calculation: 9.552800000000001E-5s]
[ printing: 7.8915E-5s])

Comment: the second one.

Comment: "the run time is still 0.21"
I guess this time includes user input (10 and 3)? Then the code improvement won't help. Exercise typewriteing.

Comment: @negar.n is the new solution still to slow? by the way this gives "nicer" result for bad input (when n<k)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `System.in` pass an input file into Scanner

> Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

Store input at input.txt file

Comment: Putting the whole thing in a string and printing it out with one call would be even faster. But i bet that's not the theme here.

Comment: @nada Ok.. I agree.. may be I ran through the question too fast !

Answer (score 0):

Using BufferedReader instead of Scanner significantly boosts your program performance and for the output instead of using System.out.print each time create a StringBuilder and append the result to it and print the string at the last only once.

Comment: The Scanner is only used to get two ints before the loops begin, so I doubt that it impacts performance. Otherwise I'd agree with you.